# Counting the unique values after group by clause

Tags: sql

I need to count students in every major for an academic year. There are three terms in a year. One student declares a different major in every terms . I need to take the last major he/she declared and count all the students in a major. So only one student for one major. 
When I do group by by major, I can't avoid the duplicates.
 I have only one table. It has everything I need.

I wrote this code. And It gives me the duplicated count.

```
SELECT MAJR_CODE, MAJR_DESC, COUNT(DISTINCT ID_KEY)
FROM STUDENT_ENROLLMENT
WHERE TERM in ('201830','201910','201920') 
and REGISTERED='Y'
GROUP BY MAJR_CODE, MAJR_DESC
ORDER BY MAJR_CODE
```

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions to get the data for the most recent term:

```
SELECT MAJR_CODE, MAJR_DESC, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT se.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_KEY DESC ORDER BY TERM DESC) as seqnum
      FROM STUDENT_ENROLLMENT se
      WHERE TERM in ('201830', '201910', '201920') AND
            REGISTERED = 'Y'
     ) se
WHERE seqnum = 1
GROUP BY MAJR_CODE, MAJR_DESC
ORDER BY MAJR_CODE
```